# How can I call the options of a SubCommand using discord.js? (v13)

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I've recently been working on a Discord bot using discord.js's lastest verison, v13, and slash commands. After reading through the documentation on GitHub, I was able to get a subcommand working in my bot:

[image]

However, when trying to get the options array from the arguments, I do not know how I can get arguments after getting the SubCommand. To my disappointment, the only function I found was [`.getSubcommand()`, which returns a string oddly enough.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getSubcommand) I was hoping it would return on object so I can get the options array from it.

How can I get the options object that's within a subcommand? Does this even exist? How can I use the string that is returned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SubCommands` are just subject to the slash command itself you may access the arguments of options provided within it like so:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'settings') {
        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'moderation_logs') {
            const user = interaction.options.getChannel('logging_channel');
        }
    }
});
```

Treat them as  normal message commands with `args` but better since all `args` correspond to the options provided even if they are different sub commands since they fall under the same interaction ( slash command ). 
Slash commands are awesome !